# Need a MySQL query that can filter the results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, row-number

Here, the chapter_id can be two or more than two. I need to query in a way that every chapter give the output of equal no. of questions.

i.e. If the total question is 50, and from 5 chapters, then each chapter should give 10 questions.

```
SELECT id, chapter_id, question, answer FROM `questions`
WHERE `chapter_id` IN (19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
ORDER BY `chapter_id`
```

I tried it by quering separate queries. i.e. first check the number of chapters and loop it through an array.

```
<?php
  $total_qsn = 50;
  $chap[] = {19, 20, 21, 22, 23};
  $avg = $total_qsn/count($chap);
  for($i=0, $i<count($chap); i++){
      $sql = "SELECT id, chapter_id, question, answer FROM `questions` WHERE chapter_id = {$chap[i]} LIMIT 0, {$avg}";
      $result = mysql_query($sql);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
          // Print the array members
      }
  }
?>
```

Isn't there any way, that, I can do the whole thing by a single query only! Thank you! Any Idea please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, chapter_id, question, answer 
FROM (SELECT IF(@chapterId=@chapterId:=chapter_id, @id:=@id+1, @id:=0) queNo, id, chapter_id, question, answer 
      FROM `questions`, (SELECT @chapterId:=0, @id:=0) AS A 
      WHERE `chapter_id` IN (19, 20, 21, 22, 23)
      ORDER BY `chapter_id`
     ) AS A 
WHERE queNo < 10
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply sir. But the way you did it, it seems complex & I wanted to know why 'queNo' was introduced?

Comment: @ManishShrestha You're welcome. queNo was introduced because I want to give id to each question chapterwise. It is easy in sql server you can use ROW_NUMBER() function but in MySQL there is no such function, So we need to implement some logic to implement this.

Comment: the inner query gave results something like this:
http://tinypic.com/r/2ngy9so/5
I don't think this is what I want.

Comment: Oh oh oh... I got it, its because of only 1, 1 data in other chapters. Thank you sir, u made my day! (y) but still the query seems complex. I will search over those variable declarations. Once again, thanks sir.